# cómo saber la longitud de un field?

Tags: tablas, textfield

quiero saber cómo obtengo la longitud de un Code que ingresa el cliente, tengo que verificar que ese field no tenga más de 4 cifras, no encuentro por ningún lado algún método como el length como para que en el trigger OnValidate pueda verificarlo.

```
field(1, Code[5]){
  trigger OnValidate
   begin
introducir el código aquí
  beging
   ???
```

end
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar la función `STRLEN`

Por ejemplo

```
if StrLen(TuCampo) > 4 Then
    Error('El campo no puede tener de 4 caracteres.');
```

Comment: gracias Jonathan!